# Is comma necessary in complex sentence with examples?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is the use of comma shown in the example below within the brackets necessary:

Example 1

> Projects consisting of six training sessions to staff and stakeholders, and supervised discussions(,) increased success chances.

Example 2

> Projects that consist of six training sessions to staff and stakeholders, and supervised discussion increased success chances.

Comment: Hi welcome to ELL. You sentence is a bit messy. To me, "Projects ... six training sessions **to** staff and stakeholders ..." seems ungrammatical. Fix that first and then it will become much simpler.

Comment: What is the purpose of including Example 2, since it does. It have the bracketed comma? If it is meant to show Example 1 without the questionable comma then: a) it's not necessary; and b) it differs from Example 1 in more ways than just the comma. Overall, it makes the question confusing, so you might want to either remove it completely, or make it clear why you have included it.

Comment: What is a project that consists of training sessions?  Wouldn't you just call those *training sessions*?   Are there many projects each with six sessions?  Do all of the projects combine for a total of six sessions?  I think *project* is too general to express anything meaningful here.  It is not clear what you are trying to express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your sentences work.  They are extremely hard to parse.

To make a complex sentence let's start with your base sentence.

> Projects and supervised discussions increased the chances of success.

Now let's identify your dependent clause.

> consisting of six training courses directed at staff and stakeholders

To construct your complex sentence all that is left to do is insert your dependent clause after the clause it modifies.  Ask yourself, *What consists of the six training courses*?  The answer is *the projects consist of six training courses* and that is where you insert your dependent clause.

> Projects, consisting of six training courses directed at staff and stakeholders, and supervised discussions increased the chances of success.

That sentence is perfectly acceptable but the compound subject joined with the word *and* is a little bit confusing when read.  It is easier to read if you insert the dependent clause after the *and*.

> Supervised discussions and projects, consisting of six training courses directed at staff and stakeholders, increased the chances of success.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not seem like the comma is necessary there because your examples are not ambiguous.

No matter whether or not the comma in brackets is used, it is clear from the context that both projects and supervised discussion increased success chances.

In general, this comma placed immediately after the penultimate term in enumeration is called [serial comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) or Oxford comma. It is sometimes used to resolve ambiguous sentences, for example in the sentence:

> I have written letters to my parents, Michael and Natasha.

it is ambiguous and not clear whether (1) I have written two letters, just to my parents (whose names are Michael and Natasha), or whether (2) I have written four letters: two to my parents, and in addition to that also two letters to my couple of friends (whose names are Michael and Natasha).

Using serial comma resolves ambiguity makes it clear that I intend to mean the (2) second meaning:

> I have written letters to my parents, Michael, and Natasha.

Sometimes, the inverse of this situation can happen and serial comma is the cause of ambiguity; to resolve ambiguity it needs to be removed. In this sentence:

> I have called my father, Michael, and Natasha.

it is not clear whether I called two people: my father, whose name happens to be Michael, and someone named Natasha; or three people: my father (who's name is irrelevant in the context), someone named Michael, and someone named Natasha.

Basically, if there is no ambiguity, it is up to your decision whether or not you want to place the comma after the penultimate term in enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

The second comma (in parenthesis) in Example 1 increases readability a little, so I, myself, would have included it. But as @Bad Chad has said, it is not strictly needed since the sentence is not ambiguous. Actually, I'd take that a bit further. The sentence absolutely does contain an ambiguity, but including the second comma doesn't help resolve it.

I'm referring to the fact that the sentence could be read in a couple of ways:

1. Two different things increased the chances of success (in something not precisely defined). One was having projects consisting of six training sessions to staff and stakeholders. The other was supervised discussions. That is, either one would do.

OR

2. What increased the chances of success (again, of exactly what is not clear) is the combination of both the projects consisting of the training, PLUS the supervised discussion. That is, you need both things.

I suspect it's the latter meaning that was intended, in which case one way of clarifying might be to rewrite as follows:

> Projects consisting of both a set of six training sessions to staff and stakeholders, as well as supervised discussions, had increased chances of success.

(I added "a set" because without it there could be some cognitive dissonance in the reader when they see "both six").